# How do I set char* to char*?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a following problem in which I can't figure out how to assign a `char*` called `funcName` to a `char*` called `fname`. Need some help, thanks.

```
#define MAX_PARMS 5

typedef enum {C_INT, C_SHORT, C_CHAR, C_FLOAT, C_INT_PTR} DataType;

typedef struct {
    char name;
    int *value;
    DataType dType;
} VarType;

typedef struct {
    char *funcName;
    VarType parms[MAX_PARMS];
    int numParms;
} FrameType;

void enterSumFunc (StackType *stkPtr, char *fname, int num, int *arr, int *sum) {
    FrameType *temp;
    //temp->funcName = fname;
    strcpy(temp->funcName, fname);
}
```

As you can see I have tried both `strcpy` and manually setting the `char*` but nothing works; both give a segmentation fault. Any help will be useful, thanks.

Comment: You're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. I'm not sure how to fix it without a better understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @godel9 I have updated the question could you help be intialize the pointer, I have never done it before thanks

Comment: @jack: See my last edit, it should answer all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is not set, so dereferencing it (`->`) will never be valid.

Based on edited code (specifying `FrameType`)

```
FrameType *temp = malloc(sizeof(FrameType));
temp->funcName = fname;
```

or

```
FrameType obj;
FrameType *temp = &obj;
temp->funcName = fname;
```

Will "work", but it's a "shallow copy" of data. If the "owner" of `fname` deletes it or changes it, then your `temp` object becomes invalid. You can either use `strdup()` to copy the name, or put a `char[]` in the `FrameType` instead of just a pointer.

If `temp` really is a temp (and doesn't have to live past the end of the function call) then the second approach is probably better.

Remember for each `malloc` you need a `free` or elase you will leak memory. The second approach shown above reduces that risk...

Comment: So how would I set temp? sorry I am a new to C and structures

Comment: Can you you help me now?

Answer (score 1):

```
FrameType *temp;
temp->funcName ...
```

dereferences an uninitialized pointer, which yields ***undefined behavior***, which in this case you are able to observe as segmentation fault. One of the possible solutions is using an object with automatic storage duration instead of pointer:

```
FrameType temp;
temp.funcName ...
```

---

Also note that

```
temp->funcName = fname;
```

assigns the value of pointer `fname` (i.e. an address it points to) to the pointer `funcName`, no copying is performed and once the memory associated with `fname` is freed, this `temp->funcName` will be an invalid (dangling) pointer and using it will also result in *undefined behavior*.

On the other hand:

```
strcpy(temp->funcName, fname);
```

tries to copy null-terminated string stored in `fname` to `funcName` and in case the string is not null terminated or there is no memory associated with this pointer, it will result in *undefined behavior* as well.

Note that:

```
typedef struct {
  char *funcName;
  VarType parms[MAX_PARMS];
  int numParms;
} FrameType;
```

only declares a pointer `funcName` so you should either explicitly allocate a memory using `malloc` before trying to copy a string to it or yet even better, use a buffer with automatic storage duration instead:

```
typedef struct {
  char funcName[255];
  VarType parms[MAX_PARMS];
  int numParms;
} FrameType;
```